# Problems displaying data from nested JSON structure

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on Sharepoint page where i want to retrieve data from the build in REST service. The data resides in a multilayer JSON structure.

The JSON structure:
[JSON file](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=2f2223028d835bc66bc7cda653fbf718)

I want to fetch data from the first entry (`entry[0]`), located under `Feed`->`Entry` But I can't seem to find the right way to collect and display this.

My code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
         url: "http://intra.site.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ExchangeRates?    $orderby=Modified%20desc",
         headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'},
         success: function(data){ 
                document.getElementById("rest_test").innerHTML =
                "<b>" + data.feed.entry[0].title + "</b>";
              }  
       });
  });
```

The code should display the title object from the first entry (`entry[0]`), but doesn't return, not even `undefined`.

Any advice on how I can retrieve data from a nested JSON structure?

Thx in advance.

EDIT:

Image of console output:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHBDQ.png)

Comment: Does success actually fire? Try added a console out there.

Comment: If you console.log data do you get your json response or undefined?

Comment: Getting an error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'entry' of undefined `

Comment: what happens when you run `console.log(data)` inside of the `success` callback?

Comment: If i run `console.log(data)` the console returns the json structure, as intended.

Comment: According to your third comment `data.feed` should be undefined. what happens when you `console.log` that?

Comment: I'm getting an undefined message in console if i try `console.log(data.feed)`.

Comment: But you are sure that `feed` is in the output of `console.log(data)`? Can you maybe post the output to pastebin/

Comment: See edit of first post.

Comment: What does running `console.log(Object.keys(data))` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by looking at your comments and the screenshot that your object is somehow mixed up. If `ApprovedRate` is one of the properties that your `entry`s have you shoud try running `console.log(data.d.results[0])` to get the object that you were trying to get with `data.feed.entry[0]`. Or am I misunderstanding your structure? A larger screenshot might help in that case.

Comment: Thx alot! This has been confusing.

Comment: Glad I could help! You helped me to cross the 1000 reputation ;)